# Minify throw http 400 error

Tags: php, minify

Am trying to test minify on my localhost, but it keeps giving a HTTP 400 bad request.
I put the min folder in the root folder of the site in my localhost i.e

```
/htdocs/test/min/
```

I used the groupConfig files to load my JavaScript files, i put the min url in my header.
The min url after config is

```
/test/min/g=jquery_plugins,module_js
```

I've tried to use the site url `localhost/test/min/g=jquery_plugins,module_js` still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this Minify Wiki: [AlternateFile Layout](http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/AlternateFileLayouts) to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Need a ? before the query string

```
/test/min/?g=jquery_plugins,module_js
```

Ugh it's making me wait 3 minutes cause I just answered a question and I'm new to this site.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when minify can't find a source file specified in groupsConfig.php.